# How to identify an specif 'thing' in an image (Image Processing)

Tags: java, image, image-processing, ocr

I'll start saying what I'm doing:

I'll take a photo with a webcam, in this photo there will be an object, always the same object, in a square format with letters inside it. I need to identify those letters. The step of identifying those letters is already done, the problem is the quality of the image coming from the webcam: it won't be the best nor in the best positioning, and the api I'm using to identify those letters requires positioning and quality.

The reason why I have a square is to help to identify where those letters are, so I can 'look for an square' in the image an then do what I've already done to identify the letters. My question is: is there more things I have to do in order to achieve this? Os is it only 're positioning the image, look for the square and then it's done'. If I need to study image processing there is no problem, I'm here because I don't even know what I have to look for.

I'm developing in Java because 'school things', so if there's already and api (I've heard and tried OpenCV, but I don't know what to do with it) it would really help me.

Thanks in advance.

***Edit 1***: As asked by Springfield762, I took some photos and I'll explain them below.

First let me explain what are the photos: the 'square thing' that will contain the letters isn't done yet, another department is taking care of it, so I had to improvise something here with pens and batteries. The letters will all be made of wood in a nice shape, I had to replace them with some Magicka cards as I don't have them yet, but the cards fits well to explain the example. I also made an example of the the square (that actually ended as an rectangle) in paint, so it has absolutely nothing of beautiful.

I took 3 photos, one using the light coming from the window, the second using the light of my room and the third using the flash of the webcam. (Sorry about links, I can't post images nor links, although I'm always here, this is the first time I post a question...)

1. *Window light:* [image: Window light]
2. *Room light:* [image: Room light]
3. *Flash:* [image: Flash]
4. *Square (rectangle) example:* [image: Square (rectangle) example]

The 'project' of the square you guys can ignore, I did it so that you can understand the images. And the reason I took 3 different photos was just to show all different possibilities that the webcam might be in. Also, the quality of the Magicka cards isn't a problem, since each card represents one letter, so it'll be easy to 'see' them.

Comment: Your question is rather broad, and you aren't likely to get good responses unless you ask a specific question. You mention OpenCV, and I think you're on the right track with that. The feature detection tutorials should be a good place to start: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html#table-of-content-feature2d and see here for using OpenCV with java: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#java-dev-intro

Comment: I agree with you, I kinda don't know what to ask because I don't know what I need, that's the problem.

Comment: If you provide sample image it will be easier to help. Without that it's just guessing.

Comment: Ok, I'll take one and post here.

Comment: I edited the post with images and some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found most answers to this question, I'll explain them below.

First it's not a square, but a rectangle, and it is still to be made. So I started testing the software using anything that was a rectangle, first I had to 'locate' the rectangle in the frame captured by the camera, then show it in the original image seen by the user, I accomplished that by:

1. Capturing the actual frame
2. Converting that frame to HSV;
3. Applying some kind of threshold (using the Core.inRange function, so that I could find a specific color in the range specified in the function);
4. Applying the Imgproc.findContours to find the contours of the rectangle;
5. Finally drawing a rectangle using the points found by the findContours;

How it ended: i.imgur.com/wmNVai0.jpg

After that I knew that I could place the rectangle in a way that all the letters inside it would be in a straight line, so I didn't need to care about the positioning of the letters. Now I had to fight with the OCR.
I chose Tesseract as it is OpenSource and seems to be a strong tool (supported by Google, that's for sure something), then I started to test some images.
In the beginning it was tough and I thought I'd have to train OCR even more, but the thing is that it has some kind of dictionary that tries to find words which are listed in this dictionary, and I didn't need that as I was looking for characters that could be in a total random way. I had to turn off that dictionary by adding the following line to a conf file:

1. load_system_dawg F
2. load_freq_dawg F

After that I had to change somethings in the image as well:

1. Transform into Grayscale;
2. Resize it by ~80%;

Original images (I can't post links...):

- i.imgur.com/DFqNSYB.jpg
- i.imgur.com/2Ntfqy3.jpg

Grayscale:

- imgur.com/XUZ9b1Z.jpg
- i.imgur.com/yjXMH5Q.jpg

Resized:

- i.imgur.com/zgX9bKF.jpg
- i.imgur.com/CWPRU3I.jpg

(Sometimes I had problems with resized images and on other moments I didn't, that's something I have to test even more.)

Then I could get some good results, though I'm still afraid as the light of the environment makes a whole difference, I still have to test it and mainly I still need the god da** base, I'll post it as an edit later.

If I did anything wrong or if anyone wants to correct me, please feel free to say it!

Comment: I won't mark this as the final answer because it still needs some testing, and I'd like to see if anyone else has anything else to say.